# Sending an Attachment with e-mail using Python

Tags: python, email

I'm trying send an attachment with an e-mail using following code. But it gives an error. Without the attachment it works perfectly. What is the problem with this code?

```
"mail5.py", line 14
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('domain', 25)
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib

    sender = 'a@a.com'
    receivers = ['b@b.com']

    from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
    from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg.attach(MIMEText(file("text.txt").read())

    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('domain', 25)
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())         
    print "Successfully sent email"
```

Comment: msg.attach(MIMEText(file("text.txt").read()) <-- missed parenthesis here.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing a closing parenthesis on the preceding line, try this:

```
msg.attach(MIMEText(file("text.txt").read()))
```